# Is it possible to unit test Spark UDAFs?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Spark UDAFs require that you implement several methods, specifically
`def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit`
and 
`def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit`

Suppose I have a UDAF X, 4 rows `(r0, r1, r2, r3)` and two aggregation buffers `A, B` in my test.
I want to see that this code produces the intended result:

```
X.update(A, r0)
X.update(A, r1)
X.update(B, r2)
X.update(B, r3)
X.merge(A, B)
X.evaluate(A)
```

Same as calling X.update on each of the 4 rows with just one buffer:

```
X.update(A, r0)
X.update(A, r1)
X.update(A, r2)
X.update(A, r3)
X.evaluate(A)
```

This way the correctness of both methods is tested.
However, I don't know how to write such a test: it does not seem that user code can instantiate any implementation of `MutableAggregationBuffer`.

If I simply make a DF out of my 4 rows, and try to use `groupBy().agg(...)` to call my UDAF, Spark won't even try to merge them in this specific manner - since it's a small number of rows, it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MutableAggregationBuffer` is just an abstract class. You can easily create your own implementation, for example one like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

class DummyBuffer(init: Array[Any]) extends MutableAggregationBuffer {
  val values: Array[Any] = init
  def update(i: Int, value: Any) = values(i) = value
  def get(i: Int): Any = values(i)
  def length: Int = init.size
  def copy() = new DummyBuffer(values)
}
```

It won't replace a "real thing" but should be just enough for simple testing scenarios.